# Magento 2.3.X - Override /checkout/cart to show my custom module

Tags: magento2, cart, overriding

I am trying to create a module that replaces the default `/checkout/cart` page. I have created `app/code/NewShop/Cart` module and it just displays a text now.

> app/code/NewShop/Cart/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="standard">
    <route frontName="checkout/cart" id="cart">
      <module name="NewShop_Cart"/>
    </route>
  </router>
</config>
```

I compiled it and when I go to `/checkout/cart` it still shows the default Magento cart page. How can I override that?

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: Eventually I want to rewrite the cart page. It's a project with a heavily customized cart system.